# Simulation of motor drive IC in SIMetrix/Simplis

Tags: motor, switch-mode-power-supply, dc-motor, ltspice, simulation

I want to simulate a DC motor driver like MIC4606-1 in SIMetrix/SIMPLIS software. The microchip provided only the SIMetrix model of MIC4606-1( Transient model:
https://www.microchip.com/en-us/software-library/analogsimmic4606 )

In stability point of view, I have to simulate my circuit in SIMPLIS environement and not SIMetrix, and I need the AC model of MIC4606-1 that microship does not provide.

Is there a way to converte the SIMetrix model to SIMPLIS model?

Is there a trick to use the SIMetrix model for AC analysis ?

Comment: I don't think you can [translate complex subcircuits to SIMPLIS](https://simplis.com/documentation/simplis/sp_semi/topics/overview_installing_models.htm).  Plus, the subcircuit is encrypted which makes it an even bigger pain to deal with.  Have you thought about possibly the opposite approach?  Use a transient simulation in SIMetrix to determine stability via using an averaged model for your switching element(s).  C. Basso talks about this extensively on his SPICE page: https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Spice.htm